# How to prohibit back or refresh using django 

Tags: python, django

this is my code :

```
def to_complete(request):
    return MobileResponseRedirect('/battle/complete/')

def complete(request):
    do_something()
    return MobileResponse(html)
```

but this method can not prevent back,

i do a Important thing in `complete` (like Increase in money in a game)

and  i dont want user to refresh the page or back to the parent page ,

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple idea would be to use a session variable, like this:

```
def to_complete(request):
    if request.session.has_key("complete_pending"):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    request.session["complete_pending"] = True
    return MobileResponseRedirect('/battle/complete/')

def complete(request):
    if not request.session.get("complete_pending", False):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    request.session["complete_pending"] = False
    do_something()
    return MobileResponse(html)
```

This approach will let the user enter just **once** in `to_complete` and `complete`. If you wanted the user to enter once again, just unset the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options I see:

1. You could redirect again after do_something():

   ```
   def complete(request):
       do_something()
       return MobileResponseRedirect('/battle/complete_msg/')

   def complete_msg(request):
       return MobileResponse(html)
   ```
2. If still concerned (especially if concerned about user cheating system), you should set some sort of flag on the server that the action has been done.  It is hard to say how to exactly do this w/out knowing more about your application.  One example might be only allowing this complete-action to occur IF the user has done some action (e.g. beat a level), and log that the action has taken place, so that the complete-action can only happen once for the level-beat-action.